# How to migrate from Sonatype Nexus 3.X OSS to Nexus 3.X Pro?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to migrate Nexus 3.X.X (LATEST) OSS to PRO? Have anyone done that before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any need to migrate, all you need to do is install your license into your current Nexus 3.x OSS instance:

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/License+Management